# What's that Doctor Who episode where there is a guy on a bike who sees an alien at the hospital?

Tags: doctor-who, aliens, episode-identification

Okay, so not a lot to go on here, trying to find an episode of Doctor Who.

All I remember was it starts with a guy on a bike who is a blogger or something, and he is the main character in this episode, not the doctor or his companions. He has a small apartment or house and uploads a video to his laptop. I sort of recall him going to a hospital later where he sees an alien and follows it, and that's where he meets the Doctor as a side character.

Comment: @Wikis In blink we don't actually see Sallys apartment/house, and when she goes to the hospital she doesn't meet an alien, she meets the police officer she met just a moment ago at the police station. Sorry, I just had to point this out. I actually thought of Elton in the first place, but that hospital confused me. It's possible that got mixed out with the New New York episode, or with the episode where we first meet 11th Doctor and Amy.

Comment: @Renttutar Heck, it could even be Smith & Jones, The Black Spot, The Power Of Three or the film. The Doctor ends up in hospitals quite a lot for some reason. And out of those tehcnically only Smith & Jones had aliens in the hospital (if you discount the Doctor himself of course).

Answer (score 7):

Okay, I finally figured this out. It is actually season 2, episode 11, "[Love & Monsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_%26_Monsters)" I was thinking about; my description was horrible.

Comment: Your description wasn't really horrible, just sounds like you're mixing up a few episodes/characters. There are elements of *Blink*, but also *Love & Monsters* (everything split over series two and three).

Comment: Pretty accurate apart from the hospital

Comment: Season 201? I know it’s been going for a while, but it’s not quite at that level yet.

Comment: @Mario sounded like a mash up of *Love & Monsters* and *The Eleventh Hour* to me

Comment: Hey Paul D. Waite. The reason i said season 201 is because it's the new series . If you watch this show on Amazon all the seasons are like this for doctor who , 101,201,301 etc. As to not confuse it with the original series I assume.